# Is there a way to change how the Android EditText highlight behaves?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-styles

I have my EditText view looking almost the way it's supposed to look. However, since the text's gravity is set to "center", the highlight behaves a little different than I would expect if it spans more than one line. Take a look:
[image]

I wonder if it's possible for the highlight to look more like this (edited in photoshop):

[image]

As an added bonus, if there is a way to have the beginning pink handle line up properly with the first word, that would be great. As you can tell from the first image, it's offset downwards and looks broken.

Thanks

Comment: Very interesting question. Would be very interested to know how this works too. One point though, for the handle concern. I tried it on my emulator too, but the first handle properly aligns with the first word. I don't know why your's behaves like that.

Comment: I looked into the handle position offset issue.. what I saw on my device (and in the first screenshot above) is the result of the text being automatically selected when the activity is started (I have 
`android:selectAllOnFocus="true"`).
Perhaps when that happens, the position for those handles aren't set properly. If I manually select the text with my fingers, the handles land in the correct spot.